# Implementing new data type in Python - without classes

Tags: python, class, types, fractions

I'm trying to implement new data type "Fractions" in Python to represents fractions, where numenator and denominator are both integers. Moreover, I have to implement four basic arithmetic operations. The trick is, I can't use classes in this task.
I thoght maybe tuples can be a good idea but I really don't know how to approach this.
Is there an easy way to solve such a problem? Any hint would really help me.

Comment: The arbitrary requirements suggest homework - SO isn't here to do it for you.

Comment: @Phydeaux: You can't, either on `object` itself or `object()` instances.

Comment: Why use `tuple`s instead of `list`s??

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "data type" without any classes? That seems like a contradiction in Python and many other languages.

Comment: You cannot, strictly speaking, since in Python, the *type* of an object is its class. But that is a bit of a pedantic point.

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems. 1) How to encapsulate the data, and 2) How to operate on the data.

First, let's solve encapsulation. Just put everything you need in a tuple:

```
half = (1,2)
whole = (1,1)
answer = (42,1)
```

See? The first item is the numerator, the second is the denominator.

Now you need a way to operate on the data. Since we can't use methods, we'll just use regular functions:

```
def mul(a,b):
    'Multiply two fractions'
    return (a[0]*b[0], a[1]*b[1])
```

Similarly, implement `add(a,b)`, `negate(a)`, `sub(a,b)`, etc. You might need a `simplify()`, so you don't end up with `10240000/20480000` after a while.

To make our object-oriented-without-classes suite complete, we need a constructor:

```
def make_frac(num, denom):
    'Create a fraction with the indicated numerate and denominator'
    return (num, denom)
```

Finally, place all of these functions in a module, and your task is complete. The user of your library will write something like this:

```
import your_fraction_lib

half = your_fraction_lib.make_frac(1,2)
quarter = your_fraction_lib.mul(half, half)
three_quaters = your_fraction_lib.add(half, quarter)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to troll your teacher, you could do something along the lines of:

```
def construct(values):
    def mul(other_fraction):
        new_numerator = values['numerator']*other_fraction['values']['numerator']
        new_denominator = values['denominator']*other_fraction['values']['denominator']
        new_values = {'numerator':new_numerator,'denominator':new_denominator}
        return(construct(new_values))
    return({'values':{'numerator':values['numerator'],'denominator':values['denominator']},'mul':mul})
```

This allows you to construct objects that contain a `mul` function that acts much like a class method:

```
x = construct({'numerator':1,'denominator':2})
y = construct({'numerator':3,'denominator':5})   
product = x['mul'](y)
print(product['values']['numerator'],product['values']['denominator'])
>>3 10
```